# JavaScript SDK variable not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I have a `fb.api` code which generate a id of my friend and now I want to assign that id as a variable but the variable is not working . can any one help me please. Below is the original code(this works **`alert(friend.id);`** ):

```
     FB.api('/me/friends?limit=1', function(response) 
     {
          if(response.data) 
          {
             $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {

        alert(friend.id);

            });
          } 
          else 
          {
              alert("Error!");
          }
     });
```

now I edited it like this(but it does not show the user id):

```
FB.api('/me/friends?limit=1', function(response) {
          if(response.data) {
           $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
        var friendid= 'friend.id';
        alert(friendid);
           });
          } 
          else {
              alert("Error!");
          }
      });
```

Please tell me how can I assign the id to a variable so =I can use that variable where ever I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this ....

```
FB.api('/me/friends?limit=1', function(response) {
      if(response.data) {
       $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {       
    alert(friend.id);
       });
      } 
      else {
          alert("Error!");
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you quoted `friend.id` which makes it a normal string

```
FB.api('/me/friends?limit=1', function (response) {
    if (response.data) {
        $.each(response.data, function (index, friend) {
            var friendId = friend.id;
            console.log(friendId);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("An error occurred!");
    }
});
```

by the ways it makes not sense you limited your call to `1` while you're using `.each();` to get the friend id!?

Comment: `.each();` i used this to generate more friends ids but just now i was testing codes thats why i did it as `1` any ways your solution is right but some one already told it :P